# Using 'twice' vs. 'double' vs. 'two times' and 'triple' vs. 'three times' vs. 'thrice' (also adverb vs. adjective)

Tags: meaning, word-choice, adjectives, adverbs

I'm wondering in which contexts which of 'twice', 'double' or 'two times' is preferred. Why? The same question applies to 'triple', 'three times' or 'thrice', where the latter is obviously dying.

I have a good feeling which is used in which contexts, but when I tried to put that into words, or find an underlying logic, I failed. My initial idea was that 'twice' is for discrete and 'double' is for continuous quantities. But then again, 'triple' is for discrete things like triple-header.

There is also some confusion of which can serve as an adjective and/or adverb. But also that 'twice' is reserved for doing (aka adverb), while double can never be used as an adverb. 'two times' seems to do both jobs.

Some examples (feel free to add better ones):

1. My car has 'twice/double/two times' ('triple/three times') the horsepower of X. (continuous)
2. My car has 'twice/double/two times' ('triple/three times') the cylinders of Y. (discrete)
3. I clicked twice vs. double-click (discrete, strangely the latter always means in quick succession)

Comment: They're all idiomatic, except 'two times', which is as rare as 'thrice'.

Comment: ... except in the table of the name. (The compound verb is hyphenated.)